# setInterval in member function of object error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a throttling queue of sorts in a nodeJS module.  I'm getting this error back:

timers.js:265
    callback.apply(this, args);
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:265:13)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)

I'm guessing that I'm doing something stupid, as usual, but is there a reason that it loses the closure scope or something when the second interval runs?

```
   var queueSvc = function(settings){
    var queue = ['bob', 'is', 'name', 'my', 'hi'];
    var svc = {};

    var runtime;

    svc.addQuery = function(queueEntry){
        queue.push(queueEntry);
    };

    svc.stopQueue = function(){
        clearInterval(runtime);
    };

    svc.startQueue = function(){
        runtime = setInterval(runQueue(queue), settings.queueInterval);
    };

    svc.emptyQueue = function(){
        //This method of emptying the array needs to change
        //if we decide to make the queue a public property
        queue = [];
    };

    return svc; 
};

function runQueue(queue){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(queue));
    if(queue.length > 0){
        var entry = queue.pop();
        console.log(entry);
    }
}

var it = queueSvc({queueInterval: 3000});

it.startQueue();
```

Comment: The code you see is all there is... the line number is in timers.js which is internal to nodejs somewhere.  The .apply call is happening in that timers.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake.  You are running `runQueue(queue)` immediately and then passing the return value of that to `setInterval()`.  That return value is `undefined` so what you are doing is essentially this:

```
runQueue(queue);
setInterval(undefined, settings.queueInterval);
```

This is obviously, not what you want.  Whenever you put `()` after a function as in `runQueue()` that means to run it immediately.   A function name or definition without `()` after it is just passing a function reference that can be called later.

So, you need to pass a function reference to `setInterval()` that can be called LATER like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    runQueue(queue);
}, settings.queueInteval);
```

---

Sometimes people understand it a bit better when you break it out into a named function (not necessary, but helpful in understanding what is going on):

```
function run() {
    runQueue(queue);
}

setInterval(run, settings.queueInteval);
```

Here you see you are passing only a function reference to `setInterval()` and letting the timer infrastructure call the function some time later.

The anonymous function in my first code block accomplishes the same thing.  It declares a second function that we can pass a reference of to `setInterval()` and when that is called, it then calls `runQueue(queue)` with the desired argument.

Answer (score 2):

This line looks very suspcious:

```
setInterval(runQueue(queue), settings.queueInterval);
```

`runQueue` doesn't return a function, in fact it returns nothing (`undefined`). You probably want:

```
setInterval(function () {
    runQueue(queue);
}, settings.queueInterval);
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement existing answers, wrapping `runQueue` into something callable works. However, you could also restructure your logic entirely.

```
var queueSvc = function(settings){
    var queue = ['bob', 'is', 'name', 'my', 'hi'];
    var svc = {};

    var runtime;

    svc.addQuery = function(queueEntry){
        queue.push(queueEntry);
    };

    svc.stopQueue = function(){
        clearInterval(runtime);
    };

    svc.startQueue = function(){
        runtime = setInterval(svc.runQueue, settings.queueInterval);
    };

    svc.emptyQueue = function(){
        //This method of emptying the array needs to change
        //if we decide to make the queue a public property
        queue = [];
    };

    svc.runQueue = function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(queue));
        if(queue.length > 0){
            var entry = queue.pop();
            console.log(entry);
        }
    };

    return svc; 
};

var it = queueSvc({queueInterval: 3000});

it.startQueue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Only one issue: you implemented a stack, not a queue.

Queues are FIFO and use push() and shift()

Stacks are LIFO and use push() and pop()

As long as the ordering does not matter, then either is fine.

Comment: Hey good point!  I got this working nicely with a command pattern implementation.  It's happily in production kicking butt :)